# CKEditor/TinyMCE does not apper or show up at text fields

Tags: wysiwyg

My CKeditor was working fine untill it suddenly stopped and does not show tabs on the body fields. I have uninstalled it and installed it again but the problem still persists.I have tried to use Wysiwyg Module and tried TinyMce but they all dont show up the tabs

- drupal 7

  - tinyMCE 4.5.1

I have gone through all the similar questions and solutions and none seem to work. i am stuck for the last 3 days. please help me out

Comment: Any error or files failing to load? You can check the Console and Network tab in your dev tools.

Comment: From the last couple days, could you list some of the things you've checked? As it is, it's pretty broad so any help reducing the available options would help.

Comment: From previous related issues on this platform i have checked jquery_update, Language default, cleared caches severally, uninstalled it and installed it again but non seem to work

Answer (score 0):

just a shot in the dark, but have you checked to make sure your text profiles are still correct? You may have to go in and reselect wysiwyg tools for your profiles.

Comment: Yes they are set correctly.

Comment: Got into another issue as i was trying to fix this --------------Warning: file_get_contents(sites/all/libraries/mediaCheck): failed to open stream: Permission denied in _locale_parse_js_file()

Comment: did you check your file permissions on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Found out the problem after turning off all the modules and turning on one by one. 
seems Responsive blocks module had a conflict with the editors. I don,t know how.
Thanks for trying to help out. Asante sana.